# Springboot config file (yml) does not resolve environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to setup different profiles, one for all our developers, one for Prod etc.

For our dev profile, I am trying to use environment variables so developers can have things like database url, username and password set up as environment variables, and the yml file will just work as is without any changes.

I have it setup like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${URL}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}
```

But for whatever reason on boot, Springboot doesn't translate the values of these environment variables, they stay as is like ${URL} and then the exception like this is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Why would these values not be translated to the actual environment variables?

Comment: You do not need special env vars. Just use env vars like `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`. Then you even do not need the properties in your YAML file. But you are right ... actually it should work. So there must be something in your environment or in your attempts to start the service that you didn't tell us.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I added that as an environment variable and took out that from the yml file as well but still same error. Tried leaving it in yml file as well.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to find out, what could be causing this to not read env variables.

Comment: I have just tested your case and it works fine. I have added the environment variable to the run configuration in IDE. And you? How did you set it?

Comment: I am on Windows, I added it using the UI from Advanced system settings.

Comment: This works either. I have tested. However I had to restart my IDE (IntelliJ) after adding the env variable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with IntelliJ.

For some reason it doesn't read the environment variables once its up and running.

As @Mar-Z pointed out, restarting IntelliJ fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Actually, there was literally no hint to the usage of any IDE in general and IntelliJ specifically. This was one of the things I meant with "there must be something in your environment or in your attempts to start the service that you didn't tell us."

Comment: I didn't think that would be a factor so didn't include that information. Thanks though! Should add here that my IntelliJ version is 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: That is not specific to IntelliJ, processes only see the values of environment variables as they were at the time the process started. That is because a snapshot of the environment variables is copied into a context specific to the application. Applications launched from within IntelliJ inherit that context.

Comment: If you want to configure environment variables within IntelliJ, you can do so in the Run configuration, section "Environment variables" of a specific run config.